F# 9 code with nullable reference feature does not compile on Visual Studio 17.6.5
I have implemented following type of code
type Foo = {
  Bar: string | null
}

and it does not compile on my machine. It does not understand "| null", which is new in F# 9.
I do have
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>

and
<PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="9.0.100" />

What is missing from my machine?
Note that I have the latest Windows Server 2012 R2 and Visual Studio 17.6.5, which is the latest which can be installed on this version of Windows.
Is it possible to use F# 9 in my machine, or do I have to rollback my changes and use F# 8?

The OS version doesn't affect the compiler. The latest Visual Studio 2022 release that added official support for .NET 9 is Version 17.12.2. It's quite likely you don't have .NET 9 SDK installed. What do you see when you run dotnet --list-sdks? Is there any 9.x version listed?


You need to have the .net SDK 9 installed (at the time of this writing, the latest version is 9.0.100). You can check this using dotnet --info. The SDK contains the F# 9 compiler that understands NRTs. I am not sure if your VS version supports this SDK, but you can build your project using the dotnet CLI.
Recommended: a global.json file setting the SDK version (if you have multiple installed) (but default is the latest)
You don't need the Fsharp.Core reference (except in very special situations)


Thanks for your response. I do have .NET 9 SDK installed. It appears that Visual Studio does not want to co-operate with newer SDKs, as it always fails when I try anything higher than 7.

I tried with Visual Studio Code and it seems to work fine!

You have an old VS version. If you install the latest version you'll see it works fine. Support for .NET 9 was released in 17.12
